# Shaded boxes sequence

Tags: pattern, sequence

I have 9 boxes, every turn exactly 4 of them will be shaded. Given the following sequence what will be the results for entries 9 and 10.

[image]

Comment: Does it have to do with rot13(qvssrerag ahzore onfrf)?

Answer (score 2):

No one seems to have made any progress, so here's the partial answer for 9:
[image: 3 out of four of the boxes have been shaded]